# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

How do I prevent the following error:

Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.'

I just changed a class based component to functional component and its not working

My source code

```
import React, {Fragment, useState} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './Components/Layout/Navbar';
import Users from './Components/users/Users';
import User from './Components/users/User';
import Search from './Components/users/Search';
import Alert from './Components/Layout/Alert';
import About from './Components/pages/About';
import './App.css';
import Axios from 'axios';



const  App  = () => {
 const [users, setUsers] = useState( [] );
 const [user, setUser] = useState( {} );
 const [repos, setRepos] = useState( [] );
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState( false );
 const [alert, setAlert] = useState( null );


// Search Github Users
  const  searchUsers = async text  => {
    setLoading(true);

    const res = await Axios.get(`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${text}&client_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}`);

   setUsers(res.data.items);
   setLoading(false);   
  };


  // GEt single github user
  const  getUser = async username => {
    setLoading(true);

    const res = await Axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}?&client_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}`);

    setUser(res.data);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  // Get users repos
  const  getUserRepos = async username => {
    setLoading(true);

    const res = await Axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos?per_page=5&sort=created:asc&client_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}`);

    setRepos(res.data);
    setLoading(false);

  };

  // Clear users from state
  const  clearUsers = () => 
  setUsers([]);
  setLoading(false);

  // Set ALert
  const  showAlert = (msg, type) => { 
   setAlert({msg, type});

  setTimeout(()=> setAlert(null),3000);
  };

    return (
      <Router> 
      <div className="App">
       <Navbar />
       <div className="container">
          <Alert alert={alert} />
          <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' render={props => (
            <Fragment>
                <Search 
                searchUsers={searchUsers} 
                clearUsers={clearUsers} 
                showClear={ users.length>0? true : false } 
                  setAlert={showAlert} 
                />
                <Users loading={loading} users={users}  />
          </Fragment>
          )} />
          <Route exact path = '/about'  component={About} />
          <Route exact path= '/user/:login' render={props => (
            <User 
            {...props} 
            getUser={getUser} 
            getUserRepos={getUserRepos} 
            user={user} 
            repos={repos}
            loading={loading} />
          )} />
          </Switch>
       </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I just change a class based component to functional component and i get these error.

0

How do I prevent the following error:

Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.'

Comment: From what I see, I think you meant to do `const clearUsers = () => {  setUsers([]); setLoading(false); }`. Because `setLoading` is outside clearUsers declaration, The setLoading() triggers render which triggers setLoading and so on.

Comment: Accept my answers :D If it worked for you @pukar . Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

As from the comment,

There was error in the declaration of function `clearUsers`

```
 const clearUsers = () => setUsers([]);
 setLoading(false);
```

which should be.

```
 const clearUsers = () => { 
   setUsers([]);
   setLoading(false);
 }
```

because of this small typo. The `setLoading` function was being called on the first render which would then call setLoading triggering react to call render again and in return call `setLoading` and caused the infinite renders.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error. I found my problem was having brackets at the end of a *function()*. Yet the function should have been called without brackets. Rookie error.

Before:

> `onClick={myFunction()}`

After:

> `onClick={myFunction}`

If you are using a button also check the **caps** of your 'onclick'.